# Difference between JDBC Driver type numbers

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, drivers

I noticed that JDBC has different Drivers like:

1. Type 1 Driver
2. Type 2 Driver etc.. to Type 4

Why did they get the name like Type 1, Type 2 etc.? Is there any logic?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The type number tells something about how the driver *actually* communicates with the database.

1. Via [ODBC API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity).
2. Via DB vendor specific API (using [JNI calls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) on e.g. a DLL file in Windows).
3. Via generic network protocol (using [sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) with e.g. TCP/IP protocol).
4. Via DB vendor specific network protocol (still with sockets).

In general (just by coincidence), how higher the type number, how better the JDBC driver performs.

Comment: vendor specific means **native** helps a little

Answer (score 10):

I believe it goes back to Sun's original (1997) [intro to JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jdbc/intro.html):

> The JDBC drivers that we are aware of
>   at this time generally fit into one of
>   four categories:
>
> 1. JDBC-ODBC bridge plus ODBC driver: The JavaSoft bridge product
>      provides JDBC access via ODBC drivers.
>      Note that ODBC binary code, and in
>      many cases database client code, must
>      be loaded on each client machine that
>      uses this driver. As a result, this
>      kind of driver is most appropriate on
>      a corporate network where client
>      installations are not a major problem,
>      or for application server code written
>      in Java in a three-tier architecture.
> 2. Native-API partly-Java driver: This kind of driver converts JDBC
>      calls into calls on the client API for
>      Oracle, Sybase, Informix, DB2, or
>      other DBMS. Note that, like the bridge
>      driver, this style of driver requires
>      that some binary code be loaded on
>      each client machine.
> 3. JDBC-Net pure Java driver: This driver translates JDBC calls into a
>      DBMS-independent net protocol which is
>      then translated to a DBMS protocol by
>      a server. This net server middleware
>      is able to connect its pure Java
>      clients to many different databases.
>      The specific protocol used depends on
>      the vendor. In general, this is the
>      most flexible JDBC alternative. It is
>      likely that all vendors of this
>      solution will provide products
>      suitable for intranet use. In order
>      for these products to also support
>      Internet access, they must handle the
>      additional requirements for security,
>      access through firewalls, and so
>      forth, that the Web imposes.
> 4. Native-protocol pure Java driver: This kind of driver converts
>      JDBC calls into the network protocol
>      used by DBMSs directly. This allows a
>      direct call from the client machine to
>      the DBMS server and is an excellent
>      solution for intranet access. Since
>      many of these protocols are
>      proprietary, the database vendors
>      themselves will be the primary source.
>      Several database vendors have these in
>      progress.
>
> The expectation is that eventually
>   driver categories 3 and 4 will be the
>   preferred way to access databases from
>   JDBC. Driver categories 1 and 2 are
>   interim solutions where direct pure
>   Java drivers are not yet available.
>   There are possible variations on
>   categories 1 and 2 (not shown in the
>   table below) that require a connector,
>   but these are generally less desirable
>   solutions. Categories 3 and 4 offer
>   all the advantages of Java, including
>   automatic installation (for example,
>   downloading the JDBC driver with an
>   applet that uses it).

Note that they didn't actually name them Type 1, 2, 3 and 4, but rather JDBC-ODBC bridge plus ODBC driver, Native-API partly-Java driver, JDBC-Net pure Java driver, and Native-protocol pure Java driver.  Each name was a mouthful, so people immediately started referring to them by their number instead.

Comment: Sadly, Oracle doesn't seem to have preserved the link to the old Sun document.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers aren't very informative. I find it more useful to think of it along the lines of:

- Local API (1,2) vs network protocol (3, 4)
- Database-independent (odd numbers) vs database-specific (even numbers)

I could never remember the numbers, but when someone said "we use a type-4 driver here", I could ask two yes-no questions to know what they were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver

Does not seem to be any logic, just plain laziness I guess!

UPDATE: The question was whether there was some logic to calling it type 1, type 2 etc instead of calling type apple, type orange :). I understand that the driver types are different and work/not work based on circumstances, but why the name "Type 1" instead of "Type JDBC-ODBC" or "Type JO" has no reason AFAIK.

Comment: There is some logic to it - Knowing the driver type helps you understand under what circumstances the driver will work.  For instance, a driver using native code wouldn't work if you can't deploy native code (say in an applet).

Answer (score 0):

In short, each Type uses a different strategy and works better for different types of implementations. I don't think it was laziness. I think it was to be able to more easily and clearly pick out which Type is best for your particular situation.