# JDBC Type 4 Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

According to the [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html), the MySQL JDCB Connector/J is a "Type 4" driver. The method I'm using to connect to the JDBC server is...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

My JDBC simply won't work, and as part of my last resort to find out why this wouldn't work, I think it could be the driver. Could someone tell me if this is the correct way to call the driver for a getConnection()? What I'm really looking for is a different command that should replace "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" for Type 4 JDBC drivers.

Here's the stack trace that led me to think why this isn't working...

```
java.sql.SQLException: No driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?user=user_name&password=pass_word
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(libgcj.so.10)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
    ... blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: No driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mysql?user=user_name&password=pass_word

This means that either the JDBC driver is missing in the runtime classpath (and you suppressed the `ClassNotFoundException` and continued on), or that the JDBC URL is wrong. There's actually an error in your JDBC URL, the `:` is missing between `mysql` and `//`. It should look like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?user=user_name&password=pass_word
```

This has nothing to do with the driver type. Note that the `newInstance()` call is unnecessary on the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. This is a leftover of a bug in its ancient predecesor `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` which registered itself with `DriverManager` in the constructor instead of in a static initializer block.

#### Related questions

- [Java connectivity with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)
- [Difference between JDBC driver type numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381337/difference-between-jdbc-driver-type-numbers)

Comment: I do have the CLASSPATH set perfectly from the bashrc file. Just to prove it, when I type "echo $CLASSPATH", it echoes the mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar directory correctly. And according to the manual, to install the driver, all I need to do is place the directory for the driver JAR in the CLASSPATH. Also, sorry about the typo, I fixed that but still got the exact same error. I've also commented out the newInstance(), but I'm still getting the same stack trace.

Comment: How exactly are you running the program? Did you understand my answer on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720284/jdbc-classpath-not-working/4720328#4720328)? If not, you have to tell in detail how exactly you're running the Java program.

Comment: BalusC, I looked at one of the related questions that really provided some detailed ways of setting up JDBC. I did what you said, but now I'm getting an error that doesn't make sense... here it is: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)...

Comment: Well, I'm running it in this way: "java -jar server.jar"... it's worked in the past. I also assume that my CLASSPATH has been correctly configured. Also, when I build the JAR in Eclipse, it also includes the mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.bin.jar in the build path of course. Other than that, I don't understand how else I should execute this. I'm sorry I sound quite amateur at this. :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still learning how to use StackOverflow's environmental. It's a pretty nice system I have to admit, lol.

Comment: As answered in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720284/jdbc-classpath-not-working/4720328#4720328), the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is **ignored** when you use `-jar` argument.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the pointer then. I guess I should use java -cp...? By the way, I'm writing a new question for the ???????????????????? expcetion I'm getting now. Hope you can answer it; you're quite helpful in letting me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As stated in the previous answer, when you want to execute it as JAR, the classpath has to be definied in its `MANIFEST.MF` file like `Class-Path: relative/path/to/mysql.jar`. As to your new problem/question, don't forget to include the relevant Java code and SQL query.

Comment: Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc tell me if that's enough relevant Java code.

Comment: I didn't expect that it came from `getConnection()`. I posted an answer anyway.