# Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1064, connector

I'm trying all I can to get a JDBC to work, the only thing that is stumping me right now is this exception, which I have no idea about:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1890)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3523)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2386)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:374)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
```

I'm using this to connect...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "username", "password");
```

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: It appears that the connection is open but there is a problem with the query syntax.  The number of question marks indicates that it could be a dynamically created in list (something like in (?,?,?)) is malformed .  Can you post the query please?

Comment: Please give more detail. It seems like you have some kind of encoding errors. What's your SQL and the default encoding of your DB?

Comment: @Steven: the stacktrace confirms that this exception is been thrown while calling `getConnection()`, not during `executeQuery()` or so.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit of a novice at this... but I simply want to say that there is not query I'm using, I get this exception right after DriverManager.getConnection();

Comment: FWIW (and it may not be worth much), I've had numerous troubles with GCJ (I'm assuming you're using it since the top of your stack dump indicates libgcj) in the past, to the point where it was better to use proprietary software rather than bask in the glow of my idealism :-) Not saying for sure that this is a GCJ problem (since my problems were quite some time ago) but the first thing _I'd_ do would be to test it with a "real" JRE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are the relevant parts:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
    ...
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1890)
    ...
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
```

Those question marks indicate a serious character encoding problem during the query to configure the client charset.

As first try, open the [my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) file and ensure that the following two entries are present:

```
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
```

As second try, replace the GCJ by [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) or [Oracle (Sun) JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which are way more robust. The GCJ is namely known to have its oddities.

Comment: Ok, so I just opened the my.cnf file at /ect/mysql/my.cnf and did a CTRL+F for those two entries and I found neither of them. Where should I add these entries, probably not just slapping it anywhere in the file right?

Comment: Yep, just *slap* them in :) With newline before and after. I would replace the GCJ anyway. Lot of your current and future troubles would disappear as snow in sun.

Comment: Ok I slapped it in there, now do I need to restart the MySQL server for this work because it isn't working just yet. Also, when I type "java" into BASH, I get gij, is this what you mean by replacing it... is gij the same thing as GCJ?

Comment: @Aero Yes, you must restart MySQL.

Comment: @Aero: I'd definitely restart it since this file is read only once during startup. As to how to replace GCJ, well, I can't go in detail since I haven't used it in practice. But in the years that I read and/or answer questions, I've seen often enough that replacing GCJ resulted in lot of miracles. Before going in detail, what platform exactly are you using? Ubuntu? Fedora? Etc. Anyway, I'd definitely give OpenJDK a try. Its installer might recognize GCJ and just replace it.

Comment: I'm using Debian Squeeze and GCJ/GIJ was the default.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH, the my.cnf entries did the trick.... you do not know how frustrating this was... I can actually go and eat my dinner now. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I would however still replace the GCJ. You never know.

Comment: For CentOS, OpenSUSE and Debian/Ubuntu, replace GCJ by Oracle (Sun) JDK: http://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/how-to-install-java-sun-jdk-in-centos-6-2/