# Java application fails to connect to mysql as non-root user in debian

Tags: java, mysql, debian

Please refer to [Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc)

I have a similar error (listed below) when run as a non-root debian user. But this error does not occur if the java application is run as a root user in debian.

The application is configured to connect to mysql as a root user.

I rebooted the system after adding the following entries in my.cnf as advised in the referred question. But the same error occurs.

```
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
```

Please help.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1026)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1751)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3425)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2045)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:298)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:65)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
   at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:840)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
   at edu.amrita.jdbc.connectionpool.bundle.DBConnectionPoolImpl.getConnection(DBConnectionPoolImpl.java:95)
   at edu.amrita.devicetalk.protocol.aesccmp.DatabaseInterface.getRegisteredDevices(DatabaseInterface.java:116)
```

Comment: Which Java distribution are you using as root/non-root user ? Try with sun-java6-jdk package (in non-free).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am using sun-java6-jre in root. But it didn't apply to the non-root user. It is still using the java supplied by debian by default  I tried this:
As a root user, created a java.sh file in etc/profile.d directory with contents 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_05/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH} 
But this didn't work. Can you please help me to make sun-java6 available to non-root user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that non-root uses Oracle Java ([`sun-java6-jdk`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sun-java6-jdk) and [`sun-java6-jre`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sun-java6-jre) packages from non-free) using [update-alternatives](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-alternatives&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) command (as root):

```
# update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gij-4.4                       1044      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.4                       1044      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java   63        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Choose appropriate number (here 2). After that there should be:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```