# Connector/J getConnection with syntax error but no syntax

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database using Connector/J but get the same message no matter what code I use. I can connect to it manually with the mysql command on debian just fine.

The error is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1`

The latest code is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class E{
  public void connect(){
    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3306/dbname?user=dbuser&password=dbpw");
    }catch( Exception e){
      System.out.printf("Something went wrong: "+e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

It fails at the getConnection call. I used print statements to figure this out as NetBeans doesn't have a problem with this (but when I put in a bad host and run it from NetBeans it doesn't complain either).

I get the exact same problem with DataSource

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
...
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource ds
    = new com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource();
ds.setServerName("192.168.1.3");
ds.setPortNumber(3306);
ds.setDatabaseName("dbname");
ds.setUser("dbuser");
ds.setPassword("dbpw");
conn = ds.getConnection();
...
```

Something is working because if I put in a bad password I get an access denied message.
I'm using  `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` and had the same problem with 5.1.21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following: [Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc)

In a nutshell, the server my.cnf file needs:

```
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
```

It also said the GCJ (gnu java compiler) is dicey, but I didn't replace it

Answer (score 1):

These might help you:

[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL](http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/1647139-you-have-error-your-sql-syntax-check-manual-corresponds-your-mysql.html)

[Problem with connecting to MySQL server](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,259743)

Answer (score 0):

Your `getConnection` statement should be 
`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3306/dbname", "dbuser", "dbpw");`

Refer [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/MysqlConnect.shtml)

Comment: There are different options on getConnection(). But I tried it anyway and it still fails.