# jdbc Error, unable to connect to sql

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i want to use database in my project, then i use this code for test( from jdbc [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm) )
and change it for my code and db
then i get this error:

```
Creating statement...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1' at line 1
Error: unable to connect to SQL!
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3020)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2949)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:538)
    at Test.main(Test.java:49)
```

my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.*;


public class Test {
    final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
    final static String USER = "root";
    final static String PASS = "";

    final static String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "UPDATE name FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1";


            Boolean ret = stmt.execute(sql);
            System.out.println("Return value is : " + ret.toString() );


            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );

            sql = "SELECT id,name FROM test";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");

                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", name: " + name);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");

            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: access problem while loading!");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        catch(InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: unable to instantiate driver!");
            System.exit(3);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: unable to connect to SQL!");
            System.exit(4);
        }
    }
}
```

my database is:
[Picture of my DB](http://axgig.com/images/70989654286815384550.gif)

i see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc) 
but it doesn't help me!

Comment: This is a basic syntax issue that you could have looked up in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first your statement is not valid update statement. It has convention:

```
update <tableName> set <column> = '<newValue>';
```

This is the simpliest update statement. It will update all rows. Then you can add [where clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to make selection of rows. Check [this out](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Secondly, you are directly adding values for columns and aren't wrapping value(s) into single quotes (they has to be wrapped otherwise it won't work). To fix it you need to add single quotes like:

```
set name = 'value';
```

---

Sure, this works but i don't like this approach. It's very dangerous and unsafe. I suggest you to use parametrized statements which are much more safe (beware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and more human-readable.

**Simple example of an usage of PreparedStatement:**

```
String sql = "UPDATE test SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, <nameValue>); // binding value for name column
ps.setInt(2, <idValue>); // binding value for where clause
ps.executeUpdate(); // executes statement
```

I would like to mention a few main advantages of PreparedStatements:

- They are precompiled, database-side caching of the SQL statement leads
  to overall faster execution and the ability to reuse the same SQL
  statement in batches.
- Automatic prevention of SQL injection attacks by built-in escaping of
  quotes and other special characters.
- Eases setting of non-standard Java objects in a SQL (Date, Time,
  Timestamp, BigDecimal, Blob, etc.)

Comment: thank you, i am reading from tuto, then i use that code, but i think the code that you say its best , i see same of this in php, but i don't know this syntax for java, then i must be learn it ,  so thanks alot

Comment: @asal you are welcome. Syntax is not hard to understand. You need to know that there are placeholders (?) which will be replaced with values from `setXX()` method(s) of `PreparedStatement` class in the same order. Indexing of columns starts from 1. You can look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: may i ask a another question? whats the first element in the code? a number of colomn , for example ps.setString(2,<namevalue>); in my database set to colomn 2 (means name) an attribute?

Comment: If you had `where id = ? and name = ?` then it will be `setInt(1, id)` and `setString(2, name)` First `?` is at index 1, second at index 2 etc.

Comment: i think i found:D if i use 3 '?' i was set must set the first element of it to 3 and second thats value , greate:D

Comment: sorry for my not understand able language:P

Comment: if you add three `?` you need to set three values.

Answer (score 2):

This Query is not correct

> String sql = "UPDATE name FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1";

modify it to

> String sql = "UPDATE test SET name='eee' WHERE id=1";

Comment: :D i test it befor but its have an error ! but now its work =))) thanks so mutch =))

Comment: I dont like this approach. its spaghetti code. Its dangerous and not very human-readable. i won't downvote you because it works but this is not correct way to do it.

Comment: @Sajmon Completely agree. Asal you should also consider using preparedStatement in future codes as suggested by Sajmon in his answer.

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change    `String sql = "UPDATE name FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1";` to

```
 String sql = "UPDATE test SET name='eee' WHERE id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option for constructing queries is to use "Prepared statements" - take a look at the oracle tutorial - [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

It helps to avoid problem with quotes like in your case and provides greater sequrity. And as I remember it provides some preparation which help to execute queries faster.

Answer (score -1):

replace:

```
 String sql = "UPDATE name FROM test SET name=eee WHERE id=1";
```

on

```
 String sql = "UPDATE name FROM test SET name='eee' WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: @all is this a correct SQL query? Why upvotes on Wrong answer